# Converting raw queries into laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this schema

`product_categories`

```
id | product_category
---------------------
1  | ABC
2  | DBC
3  | EBA
```

`store_product_categories`

```
id | category_id | store_id
------------------------
1  | 2        | 11
2  | 1        | 11
3  | 3        | 11
```

I have created a query in mysql work bench

`SELECT pc.* FROM product_categories pc LEFT JOIN store_product_categories spc ON pc.category = pc.id AND spc.store_id = 11 WHERE spc.category IS NULL;`

This query actually gets all those categories from `product_categories` table which are not present in `store_product_categories`.

Now I am really really confused how to build this is Laravel Eloq..

I did try this.

```
$exclusive_categories = Product_category::join('store_product_categories','store_product_categories.category_id','=','product_categories.id')
        ->where('store_product_categories.store_id','=',session('store_id'))
        ->where('store_product_categories.category_id','=','NULL')->get();
```

But this doesn't give me result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$exclusive_categories = Product_category::leftJoin('store_product_categories spc', function ($join) {
            $join->on('spc.category_id', '=', 'product_categories.id');
            $join->on('spc.store_id', '=', \DB::raw(session('store_id')));
        })
        ->whereNull('spc.category_id')
        ->get(['product_categories.*']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're joining on two different columns, you need to pass that through a function/closure:

```
$exclusive_categories = Product_category::leftJoin('store_product_categories', function($join) {
    $join->on('store_product_categories.category_id','=','product_categories.id')
     ->on('store_product_categories.store_id','=',session('store_id'));
})
    ->where('store_product_categories.store_id','=','NULL')->get();
```

I'm not sure if this is quite what you want. If you're looking for where store_id is NULL OR store_id = the session id, you can pass that through another closure/function.

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `product_categories` left join `store_product_categories` on `store_product_categories`.`category_id` = `product_categories`.`id` and `store_product_categories`.`store_id` = `1` where `store_product_categories`.`category_id` = NULL)

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: I edited my question. I actually wanted `category_id` to be null

Answer (score 0):

```
$exclusive_categories = Product_category::leftJoin('store_product_categories','store_product_categories.category_id','=','product_categories.id')
        ->where('store_product_categories.store_id','=',session('store_id'))
        ->whereNull('store_product_categories.store_id')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries

Comment: Did you try to execute your query?
What data was return?


$exclusive_categories = Product_category::leftJoin('store_product_categories','store_product_categories.category_id','=','product_categories.id')
        ->where('store_product_categories.store_id','=',session('store_id'))
        ->whereNull('store_product_categories.category_id')->get();